# google/cloud-storage with Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, cloud-storage

I am using google/cloud-storage (composer package) with Firebase Storage (instead of Google Cloud Buckets).

The service_account json file (credentials) was generated through Firebase console.

The authentication seems to work: `$this->handler = new StorageClient(['keyFile' => json_decode($service_key, true)]);`, but `Invalid bucket name` is all I get for all the  `gs://project.appspot.com`, `gs://project.appspot.com/bicket` and `bucket` bucket names / paths.

Do you guys know why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The bucket name is invalid because of the `gs://` because that's not part of the bucket name

Comment: Firebase Storage *IS* Google Cloud Storage, with features added for mobile apps. Exact same buckets, same APIs.

Comment: One thing to add is that by adding the `storage.objects.create` role, it complains about `storage.objects.get` and the other way around. `Storage Object Admin` won't do it also.

Comment: I actually need `create`, `get` and `list` roles, but don't know what I'm missing.